# How to create a list of users based on the roles in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a model for my users which inherits from `IdentityUser`.
Here is my model:

```
 public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNO { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }
        public Degree Degree { get; set; }
        
        //Relationships
        public string? UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public int? ClassroomId { get; set; }
        public Classroom Classroom { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Homework> Homeworks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserMajorCourse> UsersMajorsCourses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserHomework> UsersHomeworks { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to list the users based on their roles.
Here is my role class:

```
 public static class UserRoles
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string Teacher = "Teacher";
        public const string Student = "Student";

    }
```

I tried using the following method, but I received a null exception error.

```
var allStudents = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Student");
```

How can I get the list of users based on their roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all users in the user manager and then sort through them based on their roles. Similar to something like this.

```
public async List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersInRole(string role)
{
    var allUsers = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    var usersInRole = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    foreach (ApplicationUser user in allUsers)
    {
         var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
         if (roles.Contains(role))
              usersInRole.Add(user);
    }

    return usersInRole;
}
```

Comment: Based on your code above that you posted you had a _userManager? If not, you can add it through dependency injection in the class constructor:
```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```